# Time complexity difference between two containsDuplicates algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, hashmap, time-complexity

I completed two version of a [leetcode algorithm](https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate/) and am wondering if my complexity analysis is correct, even though the online submission time in ms does not show it accurately. The goal is to take a vector of numbers as a reference and return true if it contains duplicate values and false if it does not.

The two most intuitive approaches are:

1.) Sort the vector and do one sweep to the second to last, and see if any neighboring elements are identical and return true if so.

2.) Use a hashtable and insert the values and if a key already exists in the table, return true.

I completed the first version first, and it was quick, but seeing as how the sort routine would take `O(nlog(n))` and the hash table inserts & `map.count()`s [would](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/count/) make the second version `O(log(n) + N) = O(N)` I would think the hashing version would be faster with very large data sets.

In the online judging I was proven wrong, however I assumed they weren't using large enough data sets to offset the `std::map` overhead. So I ran a lot of tests repeatedly filling vectors up to a size between 0 and 10000 incrementing by 2, adding random values in between 0 and 20000. I piped the output to a csv file and plotted it on linux and here's the image I got.

[image: Plot]

Is [the provided image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NgkY.png) truly showing me the difference here, between an `O(N)` and an `O(nlog(n))` algorithm? I just want to make sure my complexity analysis is correct on these?

#### Here are the algorithms run:

```
bool containsDuplicate(vector<int>& nums) {
  if(nums.size() < 2) return false;
  sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
  
  for(int i = 0; i < nums.size()-1; ++i) {
    if(nums[i] == nums[i+1]) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
// Slightly slower in small cases because of data structure overhead I presume
bool containsDuplicateWithHashing(vector<int>& nums) {
  map<int, int> map;
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
    if(map.count(nums[i])) return true;
    map.insert({nums[i], i});
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: You can use a `set` instead of a `map`, and check the return from `insert` instead of calling `count`.  `map` is a red/black tree, not a hashed container.  (Use `unordered_map`/`unordered_set` for that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::map` is sorted, and involves `O(log n)` cost for each insertion and lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), so the total cost in the "no duplicates" case (or in the "first duplicate near the end of the vector" case) would have similar big-O to sorting and scanning: `O(n log n)`; it's typically fragmented in memory, so overhead could easily be higher than that of an optimized `std::sort`.

It would appear much faster if duplicates were common though; if you usually find a duplicate in the first 10 elements, it doesn't matter if the input has 10,000 elements, because the `map` doesn't have time to grow before you hit a duplicate and duck out. It's just that a test that only works well when it succeeds is not a very good test for general usage (if duplicates are that common, the test seems a bit silly); you want good performance in both the contains duplicate and doesn't contain duplicate cases.

If you're looking to compare approaches with meaningfully different algorithmic complexity, try using [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) to replace your map-based solution (`insert` returns whether the key already existed as well, so you reduce work from one lookup followed by one insert to just one combined insert and lookup on each loop), which has average case `O(1)` insertion and lookup, for `O(n)` duplicate checking complexity.

FYI, another approach that would be `O(n log n)` but use a sort-like strategy that shortcuts when a duplicate is found early, would be to make a heap with [`std::make_heap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/) (`O(n)` work), then repeatedly [`pop_heap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/pop_heap/) (`O(log n)` per pop) from the heap and compare to the heap's `.front()`; if the value you just popped and the front are the same, you've got a duplicate and can exit immediately. You could also use the [`priority_queue`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/) adapter to simplify this into a single container, instead of manually using the utility functions on a `std::vector` or the like.

Comment: Ok so they are both, as of now `O(nlog(n))` algorithms but the second map version is just more optimized, but I can make it truly an `O(n)` algorithm by using a `std::unordered_set` instead of `std::map` correct?

Comment: @DomFarolino: The map version has early out, so if duplicates are common, it's "more optimized"; if they're not, sorting may win due to simpler code and improve cache and memory management overhead (depends on implementation of `std::map`). But yes, `map` and `set` are logarithmic per operation, vs. `unordered_map` and `unordered_set` which are (average case) constant time for individual operations, and could reduce the overall work to `O(n)`.

Comment: Excellent. Yeah when I was thinking about it more I was thinking my second version using the map was still `O(nlog(n))` and I was confused as to why it was performing much better in my test. Thanks a lot

Comment: @DomFarolino: FYI, I just added a note on a sort-like approach that offers early out behavior like you `map` approach does (so if a duplicate is found quickly, it doesn't pay the whole `O(n log n)` cost to sort all the data). Thought it might interest you (and it would let you make a more useful comparison by having both algorithms being compared feature early out behavior).

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know that `std::make_heap` was `O(n)` until just now when I looked that up, that's pretty sweet thanks